# Exception thrown after adding style

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am attempting to add a global style to my application. After adding the  section to my App.xaml I get a confusing runtime exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll Cannot locate resource
>   'views/views/createjob.xaml'.

At design time I can see that my styles are being applied correctly in the design/preview panel in Visual Studio.

Most of the examples I've seen online show a Key property being set on the style, then being explicitly referenced by each Window that uses it. I'm looking for something that is global i.e. I do not need to go though my codebase and explicitly reference the style each time.

Full App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="TestApp.Views.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
         StartupUri="Views/CreateJob.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Full CreateJob.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.Views.CreateJob"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="CreateJob" Height="450" Width="800">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Content="Name"/>
    <TextBox/>
</StackPanel>
```

Full CreateJob.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TestApp.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CreateJob.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CreateJob : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Full App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Where is your CreateJob.xaml located? Are you referring to 'views/views/createjob.xaml' rather than just 'views/createjob.xaml' somewhere? That's that the error message implies.

Comment: @mm8 It's in the same folder and project as App.xaml ([project]/Views/CreateJob.xaml). When the style is removed CreateJob.xaml loads correctly.

Comment: @mm8 App.xaml is located under [project]/Views/. Correct, if my App.xaml just has <Application.Resources></Application.Resources> without the style it runs fine.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible sample of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mm8 I recreated a minimum project from scratch in the same structure and updated the code in my question. With the style omitted it runs and displays the basic form. With the style added it throws exactly the same exception.

Comment: @mm8 I just changed the StartupUri to StartupUri="CreateJob.xaml" and the project runs without exception and the style is applied. I'm still confused as to why the original code works without the style then throws a runtime exception with it.

Comment: @Tom  I just made the entire project and cannot duplicate the error.  I also took an existing sample project, moved MainWindow to a new folders (Views) updated the namesspaces and resource URI and could not duplicate it.  Can you please attach the solution as a zip so that we can see for ourselves?  This is odd.

Comment: @Tom Wait... You have the resource pointing to ```CreateJob.xaml```.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've provided you're looking for the wrong resource.

You have it looking for `Views/CreateJob.xaml` but you are giving us `MainWindow.xaml` with a title of 'CreateJob'. The resource uri is looking for the actual file name not the title.  Update it like so and it will work.

```
StartupUri="Views/MainWindow.xaml"
```

Comment: Apologies. This was caused by trying to provide an updated full code example. I've updated the code. The issue is still there. If StartupUri="Views/CreateJob.xaml"> without a style in the Application.Resources then the app loads fine. As soon as I add a style, I get the runtime exception and suddenly CreateJob.xaml cannot be found.

Comment: I think the StartupUri should just be CreateJob.xaml since it's in the same directory as App.xaml. I also think the error message is correct, since the relative path Views/CreateJob.xaml is wrong. However, I don't understand why this exception isn't thrown when the style is omitted. It seems to be a combination of a bug in my code (incorrect StartupUri) and odd/inconsistent behaviour by WPF.